# Compare two lists separated by commas for common and different elements in each list

Tags: bash

I have the follow two ingredient list:

1. ```
   Calcium Carbonate, Aqua, Sorbitol, Aroma, Poloxamer 407, Sodium  Monofluorophosphate (1450 ppm F), Cocamidopropyl Betaine, Zinc Oxide, Benzyl Alcohol, Cellulose Gum, Zinc Citrate, Sodium Bicarbonate, Tetrasodium Pyrophosphate, Xanthan Gum, Sodium Saccharin, Sucralose, Limonene, CI 77891.
   ```
2. ```
   Calcium Carbonate, Aqua, Sorbitol, Sodium Lauryl Sulfate, Aroma, Sodium Monofluorophosphate (1450 ppm F), Cellulose Gum, Sodium Bicarbonate, Tetrasodium Pyrophosphate, Sodium Saccharin, Benzyl Alcohol, Xanthan Gum, Limonene, CI 77891.
   ```

What I want to know is :

1. Which elements are in common
2. Which elements are present in one, but not the other

I did something that does work in python, but I'd like a more simple bash implementation.

```py
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
import os
from copy import deepcopy
from itertools import combinations

my_ingredients_dict = OrderedDict()

for f in sys.argv[1:]:
        with open(f, 'r') as myfile:
                as_a_set = set([ s.strip() for s in myfile.readlines()[0].split(',')])
                my_ingredients_dict[os.path.basename(f)] = as_a_set
all_ing_list = my_ingredients_dict.values()

common_ingredients = OrderedDict()
divergent_ingredients = OrderedDict()


for agent1, agent2 in combinations(my_ingredients_dict, 2):
    agent_key = str(agent1)+"___AND___"+str(agent2)
    agent_common = my_ingredients_dict[agent1] & my_ingredients_dict[agent2]
    if agent_common:
        common_ingredients[agent_key] = agent_common
    agent_1_but_not_in_agent_2_key = "STUFF_IN__"+str(agent1)+"__BUT_NOT_IN__"+str(agent2)
    agent1_vs_agent2 = my_ingredients_dict[agent1] - my_ingredients_dict[agent2]
    if agent1_vs_agent2:
        divergent_ingredients[agent_1_but_not_in_agent_2_key] = agent1_vs_agent2

    agent_2_but_not_in_agent_1_key = "STUFF_IN__"+str(agent2)+"__BUT_NOT_IN__"+str(agent1)
    agent2_vs_agent1 = my_ingredients_dict[agent2] - my_ingredients_dict[agent1]
    if agent2_vs_agent1:
        divergent_ingredients[agent_2_but_not_in_agent_1_key] = agent2_vs_agent1

print "========= COMMON ==============\n"
for key,val in common_ingredients.items():
        print key, val
print "=========================================\n"

print "============== DIVERGENT =========== \n"
for key, val in divergent_ingredients.items():
        print key,val
print "======================================\n"
```

In regard to the gawk solution, if I give the following list, the code produces wrong results:

(a)

```
Arginine 8%,Calcium Carbonate, Aqua, Sorbitol, Bicarbonate, Sodium Lauryl Sulfate, Sodium Monofluorophosphate (1450 ppm F), Aroma, Cellulose Gum, Sodium Bicarbonate, Tetrasodium Pyrophosphate, Titanium Dioxide, Benzyl Alcohol, Sodium Saccharin, Xanthan Gum, Limonene
```

(b)

```
Arginine 8%,Aqua , Calcium Carbonate, Sorbitol, Hydrated Silica, Sodium Lauryl Sulfate, Aroma, Sodium Monofluorophosphate (1450 ppm F), Cellulose Gum, Tricalcium Phosphate, Sodium Bicarbonate, Tetrasodium Pyrophosphate, Sodium Saccharin, Benzyl Alcohol,Xanthan Gum, Limonene, Titanium Dioxide
```

Results from gawk:

```
Common:
Cellulose Gum
Sodium Bicarbonate
Sorbitol
Sodium Monofluorophosphate (1450 ppm F)
Sodium Saccharin
Calcium Carbonate, Aqua, Sorbitol, Aroma, Poloxamer 407, Sodium Monofluorophosphate (1450 ppm F), Cocamidopropyl Betaine, Zinc Oxide, Benzyl Alcohol, Cellulose Gum, Zinc Citrate, Sodium Bicarbonate, Tetrasodium Pyrophosphate, Xanthan Gum,Sodium Lauryl Sulfate
Aroma
Titanium Dioxide
Calcium Carbonate, Aqua, Sorbitol, Sodium Lauryl Sulfate, Aroma, Sodium Monofluorophosphate (1450 ppm F), Cellulose Gum, Sodium Bicarbonate, Tetrasodium Pyrophosphate, Sodium Saccharin, Benzyl Alcohol, Xanthan Gum, Limonene, CI 77891.
Tetrasodium Pyrophosphate
Limonene

a:
Xanthan Gum
Benzyl Alcohol
Aqua
Arginine 8%,Calcium Carbonate
Bicarbonate

b:
Tricalcium Phosphate
Hydrated Silica
Calcium Carbonate
Arginine 8%,Aqua
Benzyl Alcohol,Xanthan Gum
```

Results from my python script:

```
========= COMMON ==============

a.txt___AND___b.txt set(['Sorbitol', 'Xanthan Gum', 'Tetrasodium Pyrophosphate', 'Sodium Saccharin', 'Aqua', 'Titanium Dioxide', 'Sodium Bicarbonate', 'Arginine 8%', 'Calcium Carbonate', 'Sodium Monofluorophosphate (1450 ppm F)', 'Sodium Lauryl Sulfate', 'Benzyl Alcohol', 'Limonene', 'Cellulose Gum', 'Aroma'])
=========================================

============== DIVERGENT ===========

STUFF_IN__a.txt__BUT_NOT_IN__b.txt set(['Bicarbonate'])
STUFF_IN__b.txt__BUT_NOT_IN__a.txt set(['Hydrated Silica', 'Tricalcium Phosphate'])
======================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one in GNU awk:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    FS=","                              # comma separated
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$i)           # trim off leading and trailing space
        file[ARGIND][$i]
    }
}
END {
    print "Common:"
    for(i in file[1])
        if(i in file[2])
            print i

    print ORS ARGV[1] ":"
    for(i in file[1])
        if(!(i in file[2]))
            print i

    print ORS ARGV[2] ":"
    for(i in file[2])
        if(!(i in file[1]))
            print i
}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
Common:
Xanthan Gum
...

file1:
Zinc Citrate
...

file2:
Sodium Lauryl Sulfate
```

Comment: I get `/usr/local/bin/awk: illegal statement at source line 7`

Comment: _Here is one in **GNU awk**:_ I'd assume that's not GNU awk then (`awk --version` or `awk -W version`)

Comment: Indeed, now it does _run_ but it does not work in all cases. It seems to be fine on the list provided here, but on a different list it gives incorrect results for some reason.

Comment: Try to dig up a couple of non-working cases and edit to the OP. I'll have a look.

Comment: Updated the OP.

Comment: That's because in the original samples you had strinct `, ` (comma+space) separators and that's not the case with the new data. Let me add trimming to the solution. A sec. Oh, that's also the case with @Cyrus's answer, too.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it would be great if the sort solution worked. That's way shorter :)

Comment: Untested but change all `/, /` to `/ *, */`

Comment: Doesn't work. Anyway, your solution works so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With sort, bash and uniq:

> Which elements are in common

```
sort <(sed 's/, /\n/g' file1) <(sed 's/, /\n/g' file2) | uniq -d
```

---

> Which elements are present in one, but not the other

```
sort <(sed 's/, /\n/g' file1) <(sed 's/, /\n/g' file2) | uniq -u
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It gives me the entire list of ingredients.